# Looping a Movieclip in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops

I have a simple question but can't seem to find a simple response.  I have created a movieclip inside a movieclip that contains several movieclip symbols with motion tweens.  I currently have a stop() command layer located at the end of all movieclips (frame 175) but wish to have one specific movieclip loop.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: take out the `stop()` on that specific movie clip?  It's difficult to understand what you're asking.   If what you're saying is all the movie clips are on the same timline and you want only ONE LAYER to loop, then you'll need to break that one layer out of the current timeline and into it's own MovieClip.

Comment: Do you want to do a limited number of loops and then stop you MovieClip ?

Comment: Make a new movieclip to hold the one you wish to loop continuously. This timeline will continue, even though its parent movieclip has been stopped with stop();